# How to save each row from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to save each row from a csv file. However, it is only printing the index column even though I sent the index column to false.
The following is my code:

```
def sizefcn(self):
        path1 = self.folder_path
        path2 = self.file_path
        path3 = Path(path2)
        file2=self.get_entry2()
        sizes = pd.read_csv(path3,header=None, index_col=False)
        for index, row in sizes.iterrows():
            size = row
            print(size)
```

I inputted a csv with 3 rows and no header, but it is giving me the index and the row so the output I get is

```
(0, 0    111
Name: 0, dtype: int64)
(1, 0    1111
Name: 1, dtype: int64)
(2, 0    121
Name: 2, dtype: int64)
```

but I want the output to be the numbers so : 111, 1111, 121.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `index_col` takes an integer as a paramter. It defines which column in your csv you want to use as the index. Try omitting it entirely:

```py
sizes = pd.read_csv(path3, header=None)
```

I should add that if you were to save this is a csv, you would want to include `index=False`. For example:

```py
sizes.to_csv('outputfilename.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Edit:
The for loop is also iterating over the index. Try this:

```py
for index, row in sizes.iterrows():
    size = row
    print(size)
```

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but there might be a better way than writing a function for it considering the extensive functionality of pandas. Can you explain your problem in a little more detail?

From the provided description it seems like you want this:

```py
for index, row in sizes.iterrows():
    size = row.to_list()
    print(size)
```

I tried this and it works for me:

```py
In[]: df = pd.DataFrame({0:range(5), 1:range(5,10)})
In[]: df

Out[]:
   0  1
0  0  5
1  1  6
2  2  7
3  3  8
4  4  9

In[]: for index, row in df.iterrows():
          print(row.to_list())

Out[]:
[0, 5]
[1, 6]
[2, 7]
[3, 8]
[4, 9]
```

Comment: It still prints the same thing, does not fix the issue. Could it be the for look that is incorrect?

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't paying attention. The iterator from `sizes.iterrows()` returns the index and the row, a tuple. That is, your iteration variable, `row`, actually contains `(index, row)`. Am updating my answer to address this.

Comment: Yea, I do not want it printing the index and dtype as I showed above in the question, I just want it to print the value.

Comment: Not sure if you've figured it out, but from what you've posted, it looks like your file might be tab-separated, so you will want to read the file with this command. `sizes = pd.read_csv(path3, header=None, sep='\t')`. You should have the desired function by implementing the corrections I suggested. If that doesn't work, I'd suggest refining your question and posting more supplementary material so I can recreate your issue. In the future, I suggest looking through the documentation and their examples https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table

Comment: I figured it out, in order to fix it I had to do df.iloc[i,0], to just get the entries from the first column.